# Can I use the same Preliminaries section for multiple papers in Computer Science?

Tags: publications

Some writings in **Computer Science** papers/conferences usually include the *"Preliminaries"* section, where we write the *general notations* and *basic knowledge* necessary for understanding the contents of the papers.

Can I use the same thing that I wrote in Preliminaries section for (conference or journal) paper *A*, in Preliminaries section for other papers *B*, *C* etc. also? Because basically I will need to say the same thing over and over again..

Comment: @EnergyNumbers There is definitely a relationship to this question, but the answers talk about *extensions* of previous work. So IMHO, this question should stand on its own. Also, the section title "Preliminaries" implies pretty much that the author does not claim any credits about what is written in that section - which may have an impact on the question.

Comment: @DCTLib the point is that the answer to this question is already present on the other question.